# Very simple RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have index.php with only one line in it

```
<?php echo $_GET['a']; ?>
```

And also I have a .htaccess with only two lines in it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?a=$1
```

Why when I enter `/ab.cd` I get a 404 error, but if I entering `/abcd.` it doesn't give me a 404 error and PHP echos `abcd` (without the dot on the end of the url).

Can anybody tell me why my rewrite rule allows `abcd.` through instead of giving me a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I've just tested your Rewriterule (standalone) in my dev environment and it works. It doesn't allow `/abcd.` through on mine - It gives me a 404 error, so there must be something somewhere in your environment that's affecting your rules.

**-initial post-**

Looks like the period(.) in your `/ab.cd` isn't defined in the Rewriterule - just lowercase a-z chars.

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z.]+)$ ?a=$1
                  ^
```

Comment: In this case PHP echos only abcd (without the dot on the end of the url) but doesn't give me a 404 error.

Comment: I think he's more interested in the 2nd case, why `abcd.` doesn't yield a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you've used, `([a-z]+)`, matches only the lowercase letters "a" through "z". It will never match a series of letters followed by a period followed by a series of letters, like your attempt with `ab.cd`.

If you want to match periods as well, you need `([a-z.]+)`.

Comment: I want get 404 error if I entering /abcd. (with dot in the end of the url)

Comment: The expression you're using shouldn't match `abcd.`. At a guess, maybe  your browser is stripping the period off? That would seem like very incorrect behaviour, but I can't suggest anything else to check off the top of my head.

Comment: @meagar It's possible that that's punctuation in the OP, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If I enter /?a=abcd. PHP echos abcd. but if I entering /abcd. PHP echos only abcd (without the dot on the end of the url). Why it happining?

Comment: I've modified your question to make it clear that you're not looking to allow periods through, that you're actually more interested in why a period works with `abcd.`.

Answer (score 0):

I just rebuilt the situation on my server and I'm getting the desired 404 error. I only added the `[L]` flag to the RewriteRule.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ test.php?a=$1 [L]
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['a']; ?>
```

Are there maybe any other rewrite rules following that might interfere with your request? Even in other files that get included? In that case, the L flag might help you.